# get svg element from an xml response

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml, svg

When i try to access the reponse xml i get errors. i want to access the svg firstly and then get the height and width of the svg viewbox or an alternative way. how can i access the svg from the response xml to get the height and width?

I want to access the height and width using javascript (maybe jquery) like so:

this._imageW = jQuery(".SVGImage").width();
this._imageH = jQuery(".SVGImage").height();

i am using a method to download the file and then give me the response in xml. idk how to access the elements withing the xml reponse thought.

[image]

this is the reponse above.
i tried this in the console but doesn't work
[image]

how can i access the height and width of the svg element?

Comment: btw in the console for the first image you see 'c' this is a variable that represents: var c = atob(btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(event.getParameter('response'))))) this variable contains the xml format code. I want to get the height and width of this variable now. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The correct function call is `getElementsByTagName()`. Note the 's'.  I am not sure if this is your only problem, though, because there is not enough info in your question.  If it is still not working, please provide a working sample of your code.

Comment: `c` looks like a string

Comment: yes c is a string. how can i access the svg within the string? :) @KevinB

Comment: if it's a string, you can't treat it like a dom node collection, it has no getElementsByX methods.

Comment: how can i convert it so i can access the dom? is there a way?

Comment: @KevinB how can i convert it so i can access the dom elements?

Answer (score 2):

You're going to want to parse the string `c` into HTML using the jQuery function `$.parseHTML()`.

From that, you will then have a variable which can be accessed by your `getElementByX()` calls and can find the SVG element you want.

```js
var c = '<svg width="200px" height="100px" viewbox="0 0 100 50"> <path d="M50,35 a20,20 0 1,0 0,-20 a20,20 0 1,0 0,20z" fill="white" stroke="black"></path> </svg>'

var html = $.parseHTML(c);

$('#width').html($(html).attr('width'));

$('#height').html($(html).attr('height'));

$('#output').html($(html));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Height: <span id="height"></span>
</p>
<p>Width: <span id="width"></span>
</p>

<div id="output"></div>
```